# How to share python libraries from host to multiple docker containers?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip, microservices

We have a setup of multiple docker containers running python microservices. The problem is that a lot of libraries are redundant across the containers. Because of docker isolation, all the libraries are independently installed in each container which is increasing the docker image size.

So, is there a way in which I can share the python libraries across multiple containers by maybe installing all the libraries in the shared folder or any other solution, keeping the code still isolated but allowing to use the shared libraries?

Dockerfile1:

```sh
FROM python:3.8.5-slim

RUN apt-get update && \ 
        apt-get install -y \
        git openssh-server 

# Avoid cache purge by adding requirements first
RUN git clone git@github.com:some_org/some_repo_1.git
WORKDIR ./some_repo_1/

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Dockerfile2:

```sh
FROM python:3.8.5-slim

RUN apt-get update && \ 
        apt-get install -y \
        git openssh-server 

# Avoid cache purge by adding requirements first
RUN git clone git@github.com:some_org/some_repo_2.git
WORKDIR ./some_repo_2/

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 81

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "81"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```sh
version: "3.9"
services:
        service_1:
                build:
                        context: './some_repo_1/'
                ports:
                        - '80:80'

        service_2:
                build:
                        context: './some_repo_2/'
                ports:
                        - '81:81'
```

**NOTE:** we have to deploy a lot of different microservices docker container having somewhat similar dependencies. So docker image size is a major concern.

**PS:** I am using docker-compose to run the multiple docker containers.

Comment: This sounds like you shouldn't use docker in the first place. However a solution could be having the core libs that you need in a folder which you are going to share between the containers via the volumes option.

Comment: Sounds like you should just be creating a base image with all of the dependencies and then building your service images on top of that.

Comment: @Dimitar I already tried using volumes option, but I am not able to source the python venv in other containers. I get your point of not using docker, but the problem statement requires me to isolate the code.

Comment: @larsks After creating the base image, i have to clone a git repo on this image and these repo are separate repo's on all the containers. So this makes a duplicate image of somewhat same size.

Comment: Could you share two of the Dockerfiles you are using?

Comment: @snahor there are somewhat 20-25 dockerfiles which are using almost same libraries. So it's not possible to share them. But the whole process is something like: 1) taking the base python file. 2) clonning git repo 3) installing requirements 4) running the server.

Comment: I mean to share the dockerfiles here, I wanna take a look at them.

Comment: @snahor I will share a mock dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

Comment: @snahor Any idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: @DipanshuKumarSuman did you find a solution to this? If so, could you help with the solution? Please

Comment: @abhi You can refer to the below solution if all your python container use same library and same version(which is not my case).

Comment: @DipanshuKumarSuman my containers do share common packages, however, some have one to two extra libraries, and, some have a bit less.
But the below process just layers on top of the common folder, which, results in unnecessary storage of spaces.

Comment: @abhi you can install all the shared packages and then share it as a volume. this way you wont need to create another base image like described below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you can split your requirements into a "common" set, and some additional per-application dependencies.  In a non-Docker environment, you might run:

```sh
python3 -m venv venv1
./venv1/bin/pip install ./requirements-common.txt
./venv1/bin/pip install ./some_repo_1/requirements.txt
./venv1/bin/uvicorn ...
# and similarly for venv2, some_repo_2
```

You can build your own intermediate Docker image that only contains the common libraries:

```sh
FROM python:3.8.5-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements-common.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements-common.txt
```

```sh
docker build -t my/app-base .
```

Then when you build your per-application images, you can depend on that as a base image and have that library set preinstalled.  The way the Docker layering works, the underlying library set will be shared across the various derived images.

```sh
FROM my/app-base
# Inherits WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 81
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "81"]
```

Compose doesn't have any specific support for this pattern.  If the intermediate image consists of just a set of preinstalled libraries that changes rarely, it might be easiest to manually `docker build` it as needed, and use the `docker-compose.yml` you have in the question as-is.

Comment: Yeah, I can use a prebuilt image with common libraries, but still the problem is that all the other images which will be build using this as base image will have those common libraries, making it redundant. And it affects the size of the images

Comment: They should be able to share the base image.  Even if the same libraries are included in the common list and the per-service list, Pip should know to not reinstall libraries that are already there, so the per-service images should only have the service-specific library dependencies plus the actual service code.

Comment: I agree with you but my point here is that the base image i create, lets say of "x" size, and whenever i use this to build other images this "x" get added into each one of them. That means if i am building 10 images, the total size used will be 10x. Thats why i want to propose a solution somewhat like all the other containers will be sharing the same library folder (or say, venv).

Comment: The point of this setup is that the "x" gets shared between all of the derived images; it does not get duplicated between them.

Comment: No, it gets copied in each container resulting their size to be "x"+something. just to be sure, i tried the setup you suggested and created 3 images. 1) base image with common library (size=533mb) 2) app image using base image(created in last step) with just one extra library (size=534mb) 3) another app image using original python image and that 1 library size(=120mb). So, that image being the base image for other container ends up being copied into them.

Comment: An interesting conversation. I think there are two sizes being discussed here: size of storage needed to store all docker images and the actual docker image size. Using shared layers definitely decrease the storage needed, where it doesn't affect individual docker image size. I think using shared volume is the only possible way to actually decrease docker image size. Yet isn't it defeating the purpose of using Docker?